# Access sql Query problem

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm not getting proper result from this query.

```
SELECT Qty as op, 
       0 as secunit 
  FROM tbl_master 
 WHERE tb_sno = 1 
UNION
SELECT main_qty as op,
       main_unit as secunit 
  FROM purchase 
 WHERE tb_sno = 1 
   AND TRN_DATE < #2011/05/14# 
   AND trn_sno2 <> 0
```

This show less one record from actual. is there any way to get actual result

Comment: Have you tried using UNION ALL? Perhaps there is a duplicate record in one of those recordsets.

Comment: @fortheworld you should probably make that an answer

Comment: @fortheworld: With only two columns like this there doesn't seem to be much sense in keeping the duplicates in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using UNION ALL? Perhaps there is a duplicate record in one of those recordsets. (making my comment an answer)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both of your queries set the exact same criteria on the tb_sno field (`WHERE tb_sno = 1`).  Because of that, if op and sec_unit have the same resulting values in each query, a `UNION` will eliminate one of the duplicate rows.  A `UNION ALL` will keep all duplicates, as fortheworld mentioned.